# Android получение fragment map из fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Необходимо получить статический фрагмент google maps из моего фрагмента. Однако выдаёт ошибку что не соответствует фрагменту. Вся проблема, что SupportMapFragment наследован от V4 фрагмента. Как получить этот фрагмент?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="isttechnology.project.MapsActivity" />
</LinearLayout>


public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
      SupportMapFragment mapFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `MapView` для карт в вашем фрагменте:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

В коде инициализируйте карту:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```